# What's the "right way" to design Django models for this use case?

Tags: django, database-design

I'm slightly confused about what the "right way" is to design Django models for this particular use case.

I have models called Book, User, Rating. I'm designing an app that let users rate books.

Rating has a many-to-one relationship with user and a many-to-one relationship with Book.

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name=ratings)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,related_name=ratings)
    ...
```

With this design, I can't work out how to enforce the rule that a user can only rate each book once. I'm also not sure whether this is the right way to design models for this use case. So if I could get a few pointers in the right direction, it might help me avoid design flaws at this early stage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the unique_together Meta option on your Rating model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/options/#unique-together